# How do I free up disk space?

Tags: server

My Ubuntu cloud server has left only 900MB of disk space.

I'll just empty the directory /tmp and wondering if there is any other location to clean up.

Comment: Try this one too: dpkg -l | grep ^rc | cut -d ' ' -f3 | xargs sudo apt-get purge -y

Comment: If you are using docker: https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning

Comment: for many cases:
`sudo docker container prune -f && sudo docker image prune -f`

Comment: @crsuarezf Care to give some explanation as to what this does?

Comment: TBH, I'd rather use Alpine for docker containers then Ubuntu, if space and disk size is an issue.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

That can clean out a lot of guff (old kernels, etc) that have been replaced. You can do a similar thing in Synaptic (load it up and select the status button and then the Auto-removeable option).

Comment: will it not affect running applications like if it removes any necessary package on which any application depends?.

Comment: No. Autoremove looks for orphaned packages, that is to say packages that you didn't explicitly install yourself (ones marked auto) and that have no dependencies. If you use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`, it can clean up as you go but it's quite common for older installations to collect a raft of installed kernels as security updates come out.

Comment: Thank you!. I have atleast 1.1GB of free space. How about using apt-get autoremove?

Comment: Typo in my last comment. I meant to say that orphaned packages are ones that aren't depended on, not ones that "have no dependencies". They may well have dependencies and if they were only there for that orphaned package, they'll be removed too. Some times (with really deep dependency trees) it can take a couple of autoremoves to clean up.

Comment: While the above command is certainly useful, it will **not**, as stated, remove old kernels. That has to be done either manually or with additional tools like Ubuntu Tweak.

Comment: @nyarlathotep It _will_ remove kernel header files, which at first glance may make one think it's removing the old kernels - the old kernels remain, however (try `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image`).

Answer (score 267):

To delete downloaded packages (.deb) already installed (and no longer needed)

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

To remove all stored archives in your cache for packages that can not be downloaded anymore (thus packages that are no longer in the repository or that have a newer version in the repository).

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

To remove unnecessary packages (After uninstalling an app there could be packages you don't need anymore)

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To delete old kernel versions

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-X.X.XX-XX-generic
```

If you don't know which kernel version to remove

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image
```

**Source:** [Limpiando Ubuntu: comandos y programas (actualización)](http://www.glatelier.org/2010/10/limpiando-ubuntu-comandos-y-programas/) ([google translated](https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fglatelier.org%2F2009%2F03%2F02%2Flimpiando-ubuntu-comandos-y-programas%2F&edit-text=))

Comment: Running `clean` freed up quite a bit of space. Immediately after, I ran `autoclean` and my free space went _down_ by 45MB. Running `clean` again released this extra space.

Comment: I removed all the linux image listed by `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image` which caused me a boot error - the ubuntu disappeared from grub boot menu - [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/318524/154971) fixed the problem - try not remove the latest image

Comment: What exactly are we doing when we remove the linux images?

Comment: Ok, this has already been answered 100 times (& in this thread also), **but** I find it _really_ strange to be upvoted 160 times, because: 

`sudo apt-get clean`

It will -simply- [remove the packages all the local copy of the packages that you may have downloaded when doing an installation +upgrade. This will almost empty the /var/cache/apt/archives directory.](https://askubuntu.com/a/485404/75115) 

... So the next time you run `sudo apt-get update` it **will** re-download everything (already there). Just a heads-up!..:)

Comment: @Nostromov No, `sudo apt update` downloads the list of available packages, not the .deb installers (which `sudo apt clean` cleans).

Comment: should I remove all `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image`

Answer (score 234):

- Show top 10 biggest subdirs in the current dir.

  ```
   du -sk * | sort -nr | head -10
  ```

you can create this as an alias in your say: ~/.bashrc and use it

```
    alias ducks='du -cks * | sort -rn | head'
```

- Use File Usage Analyzer (AKA baobab; GNOME based), Filelight or kDirStat (KDE based), to see where the disk space is going visually (`ncdu` uses a TUI).
- Check if you have old kernels for deletion

  ```
   ls -lh /boot
  ```
- Cleaning packages

  ```
   sudo apt autoremove
   sudo apt autoclean
  ```

  see list of all installed packages, sorted by size. If you see something big and don't use it - uninstall it

  ```
   dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Installed-Size} ${Package}\n' | sort -nr | less
  ```
- Clean unused language files with translations (there are tons of them)

  ```
   sudo apt install localepurge
  ```
- Check content of /var/tmp/

  ```
   du -sh /var/tmp/
  ```
- Check also

  ```
   man deborphan
  ```
- Search for big files:

  ```
   find / -type f -size +1024k
  ```

  or

  ```
   find / -size +50000  -exec ls -lahg {} \;
  ```
- Big installed packages (part of the package: debian-goodies)

  ```
   dpigs
  ```

  or [`wajig sizes | tail -30`](https://wajig.togaware.com/).
- On systemd: Remove the oldest archived journal files until the disk space they use falls below the specified size

  ```
   sudo journalctl --vacuum-size 10M
  ```
- [Limit Tracker disk usage](https://askubuntu.com/a/465215/349837).

Comment: To find big files I suggest `ncdu`, which provides a fast way to see what directories are using your disk space

Comment: `kDirStat` is replaced by `baobab`

Comment: After running ` sudo journalctl --vacuum-size 10M` I am getting `Warning: journal has been rotated since unit was started, output may be incomplete.` message , how could I fix it?

Comment: `baobab` is wow Bob!

Comment: @rubo77 `ncdu` is not fast compared to `baobab`, at least on my WSL 20.04 - because it gets confused by windows/linux file systems `/mnt/c/...` and scans my entire drive, not just WSL.

Comment: `ncdu / -x` is a good use in WSL (to avoid scanning outside disks)

Comment: Your `dpkg-query` line gives me many `linux-modules-extra-5.x.x.x-generic`.  and also a bunch of somewhat smaller `linux-image-4.x.x.x-generic`.  How can I uninstall all of these?? How can I uninstall only the ones I don't need?

Comment: @jet (Or, actually: is there a problem in your command? It's displaying the installed size, even for packages that are not installed ! )

Answer (score 27):

I just freed up almost 2 gigs by removing old kernels and header files:

use

```
uname -r
```

to check your current version, then

```
dpkg -l linux-image-* linux-headers-*
```

to see all the old kernels and header files, then

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-<XYZ> linux-headers-<XYZ>
```

the `apt-get remove` command supports wildcards, so you can do `apt-get remove linux-image 3.0.* linux-headers-3.0.*` for example, to get rid of many at once.

Make sure you don't kill remove current kernel of course!   And maybe keep one or two old version, just in case... but not 10 or 20!

Comment: That bit about wildcards ? Before making use of it I would double-check that because I tried it and I got more than I wanted. It's possible (perhaps even likely) that I stuffed up in some way but I don't know how and yet I lost more headers than I wanted .

Comment: The wildcards are regex wildcards rather than globs.

Comment: There should be some autoremove for old kernel...

Answer (score 22):

Do not forget to Empty Trash.

[image: screenshot]

Or from command line:

```
rm -r ~/.local/share/Trash/info/ && rm -r ~/.local/share/Trash/files/
```

Or just `trash-empty` using trash-cli package.

Comment: `rm.sh: ~/.local/share/Trash/info/: No such file or directory` can I directly do `command rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*`?

Comment: Why you are trying "rm.sh" instead of "rm"?

Comment: I was using `shell-safe-rm` (https://github.com/kaelzhang/shell-safe-rm)

Comment: Notice that with "shell-safe" you won't actually delete any file, as they state at github site "Using safe-rm, the files or directories you choose to remove will move to $HOME/.Trash instead of simply deleting them".

Answer (score 19):

## Uninstall large packages that you don't use

Some packages can be quite large. A convenient way of finding these is to use `dpigs`. It's not installed by default but can be found in [`debian-goodies`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-goodies) ([GitHub project](https://github.com/tpo/debian-goodies))

```
sudo apt-get install debian-goodies
```

Then:

```
$ dpigs
419576 texlive-latex-extra-doc
204112 nvidia-319
175463 google-chrome-stable
141058 linux-image-extra-3.11.0-15-generic
113173 libreoffice-core
104822 valgrind
102322 qt4-doc
93337 blender
91105 texlive-pstricks-doc
90517 libboost1.53-dev
```

There are a few options:

```
-n, --lines=N
  Display the N largest packages on the system (default 10).
-s, --status=status-file
  Use status-file instead of the default dpkg status file.
-S, --source
  Display the largest source packages of binary packages installed
  on the system.
-H, --human-readable
  Display package sizes in human-readable format (like ls -lh or du -h)
-h, --help
  Display this message.
```

Comment: Another alternative: [`wajig sizes`](https://wajig.togaware.com/)

Comment: Should I remove them using `sudo apt-get purge <app>`?

Answer (score 17):

I really recommend you the program BleachBit, which cleans everything on Ubuntu. Install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt install bleachbit
```

Comment: Would be nice as you can share more details at `which cleans everything on Ubuntu` > A great graphical GUI tool to fit all needs https://askubuntu.com/a/18459/349837

Answer (score 17):

### Remove all old kernel versions automatically

> **Attention:** If you've just upgraded the kernel, reboot before deleting the older versions!

Remember to check which kernel you are using type:

```
uname -r
```

Then as root:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d')
```

read [that thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) to be safe not to remove needed kernels with this command!

If you run into problems, use this script instead: https://askubuntu.com/a/1409370/34298

Answer (score 14):

Check for large numbers of log files too:

```
sudo du -h /var/log
```

Or as [rubo77](https://askubuntu.com/users/34298/rubo77) points out in commends, you could use the NCurses disk usage tool:

```
sudo ncdu /var/log
```

Comment: handy command which lists the file size and not "number of log files"

Comment: or use `sudo ncdu /var/log`

Comment: Check out `logrotate` for how to purge older logs; though under systemd logs are handled by journald and so you'll need to look at the journald conf files.

Comment: Thanks `/var/log/mongodb` had 5 GB . Would it be fine to delete all logs?

Answer (score 14):

#### Cleaner script

This script will execute the biggest chunks on the console:

- Clean apt cache
- Remove config files left from uninstalled .deb packages (happens if you don't use the `--purge` switch with `apt-get`)
- Remove every kernel except the one you are using
- Empty the trashes of every user(including root)

create a file with this content and give it executable rights:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Adapted from 71529-ubucleaner.sh - https://web.archive.org/web/20151209182520/http://opendesktop.org/CONTENT/content-files/71529-ubucleaner.sh

OLDCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')
CURKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')
LINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"
METALINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"
OLDKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $LINUXPKG |grep -vE $METALINUXPKG|grep -v $CURKERNEL)
YELLOW="\033[1;33m"; RED="\033[0;31m"; ENDCOLOR="\033[0m"

if [ $USER != root ]; then
  echo -e $RED"Error: must be root! Exiting..."$ENDCOLOR
  exit 0
fi

echo -e $YELLOW"Cleaning apt ..."$ENDCOLOR
aptitude clean
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean

echo -e $YELLOW"Those packages were uninstalled without --purge:"$ENDCOLOR
echo $OLDCONF
#apt-get purge "$OLDCONF"  # fixes the error in the original script
for PKGNAME in $OLDCONF ; do  # a better way to handle errors
  echo -e $YELLOW"Purge package $PKGNAME"
  apt-cache show "$PKGNAME"|grep Description: -A3
  apt-get -y purge "$PKGNAME"
done

echo -e $YELLOW"Removing old kernels..."$ENDCOLOR
echo current kernel you are using:
uname -a
aptitude purge $OLDKERNELS

echo -e $YELLOW"Emptying every trashes..."$ENDCOLOR
rm -rf /home/*/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null

echo -e $YELLOW"Script Finished!"$ENDCOLOR
```

Adapted from [71529-ubucleaner.sh](https://web.archive.org/web/20151209182520/http://opendesktop.org/CONTENT/content-files/71529-ubucleaner.sh)

#### Find large folders and packages

Some tools that will help you find large folders and packages:

```sh
sudo apt install ncdu debian-goodies deborphan
sudo ncdu -xr /  # lists all folders by size on the console (like the gui `baobab`)
dpigs -H         # shows large packages that you don't use
man deborphan    # finds packages that have no packages depending on them
deborphan --guess-all --libdevel | xargs apt-get -s purge
```

#### Localepurge

Use localepurge to uninstall unused languages in your system:

```
sudo apt install localepurge
sudo localepurge
```

#### Remove old snapd images

```
LANG=c snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' | \
    while read snapname revision; do \
        snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"; \
    done
```

More [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1141683/349837).

#### Bleachbit

A great graphical GUI tool to fit all needs:

```
sudo apt install bleachbit
```

More info about Bleachbit [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/18459/349837).

#### Clear pythons pip cache

```
pip cache purge
sudo pip cache purge
```

#### Check your temp and cache folder

```
ncdu /var/tmp
ncdu /var/cache
```

#### Remove manpages and documentation

Additionally you can remove manpages and documentation as described in the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReducingDiskFootprint#Documentation):

Create a file /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/01_nodoc which specifies the desired filters. Example:

```sh
path-exclude /usr/share/doc/*
# if we need to keep copyright files for legal reasons:
# path-include /usr/share/doc/*/copyright
path-exclude /usr/share/man/*
path-exclude /usr/share/groff/*
path-exclude /usr/share/info/*
# lintian stuff is small, but really unnecessary
path-exclude /usr/share/lintian/*
path-exclude /usr/share/linda/*
```

Remove the same set of files and directories in the project-config's postinst. Example:

```sh
echo "Removing documentation..."
# if we need to keep copyright files for legal reasons:
# find /usr/share/doc -depth -type f ! -name copyright | xargs rm || true
# else:
find /usr/share/doc -depth -type f | xargs rm || true
rm -rf /usr/share/man/* /usr/share/groff/* /usr/share/info/* /usr/share/lintian/* /usr/share/linda/* /var/cache/man/*
```

Comment: I got a warning executing this script that I was about to remove a kernel with the same version number as I was running.

Comment: check the current kernel you are using with `uname -a`. In case you just did an apt-get ugrade before and got a new kernel, this could be the cause, that the current kurnel you are using is not the newest that is installed? Do a repoot then before starting this script

Comment: I find `debfoster` better than deborphan. Also, `popcon-largest-unused`. Someone already mentioned `kdirstat` and `bleachbit` (which IIRC has a dupes finder).

Comment: Depending on your case, you can find some more options in this script: https://github.com/boxcutter/debian/blob/main/script/minimize.sh

Answer (score 10):

Try using BleachBit ([located at sourceforge](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/)).  It is a great program. 
the basic idea is that it quickly frees up disk space and removes a lot of the junk that is hidden in the system. There are about 70 applications that it can recognize and wipe clean.  There is also the ability to use it to "wipe" the free disk space. I think of it as CCleaner from windows only for linux.

Comment: Note that the question specifically asks for server tools and this is a desktop program (requires X display).

Comment: Best tool till now!

Answer (score 8):

If you use UFW, check the log folder. On one of my machines, UFW was generating 8Gb of logs in a couple of days.

You could also empty the apt cache with:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Comment: Were I can find UfW log files ?

Answer (score 5):

First, there is a tool for listing all big folders and files. Just type 'Baobab' into the launcher. By removing folders and files you don't need you get more space.

---

Then, there is a program for removing double files. The program is called `fslint`.
Install it by entering

```
sudo apt-get install fslint
```

in a Terminal.

or graphically

[image: Install fslint via the software center]

---

You can also clear the package cache with

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

---

The fourth step is to remove old Kernel entries.
You can do this by installing and opening Synaptic. In Synaptic, search for the old Kernel entries (every Kernel entry that is displayed in GRUB except the newest) and remove it.

---

One good step is to remove the application cache. Do this by installing and running `bleachbit`:

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

or graphically

[image: Install bleachbit via the software center]

**Important: Deleted cache cannot be restored!**

---

The last step is to defragment the file system. 
Do the following for this:

```
cd $HOME
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git
cd e2fsprogs
./configure
make
```

---

With these commands, you download and compile e2fsprogs. (If you or the community has got a better way to install the program, please edit!)

Also make sure that `git-core` is installed. 
If not, execute:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

or using Software Center [image: Install git-core via the software center]

Now you can run the program with:

```
cd $HOME/e2fsprogs/misc
./e4defrag /dev/sda1    #defragment /dev/sda1
./e4defrag -v /dev/sda1 # verbose output
./e4defrag -c /dev/sda1 # see overview of fragmentation status
```

Replace /dev/sda1 with the file system or folder/file you want.
Note that for defragmenting a device (such as HDD) you need root privilegs, but not for your own files.

---

**Source (German): [here](http://www.mypcsupport.de/net/linux/ubuntu-aufgeraumt/)**

Comment: Wow, deleting old linux-header and linux-image versions freed up about a gig and a half on my 10.04 install.  fslint is a great find as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Instead of baobab you can also use the commandline tool ncdu to find large folders and files: `sudo apt-get install ncdu`

Answer (score 3):

The `/tmp` directory should never be cleaned up manually unless absolutely necessary (ie: a closed application didn't clean-up after itself).

You can search where space might be filling up using the 'du' command; usually places of interest are inside `/var`. To name two usual suspects `/var/log` and '/var/cache'. Though I've had some users who install a backup utility and never realise that it creates GBs of incremental backups in `/var/backup` that build up over a week or month to fill the entire disk space.

Comment: Thank you!. As you said I have some space occupied in MBs under /var/cache and wondering how to remove unnecessary files.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ubuntu-tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) to clean.

it cleans all *.deb that are downloaded to installation apps.

Comment: not working with KDE

Answer (score 2):

If you have already deleted a lot of junk but disk space does not seem cleaned just reboot ubuntu. Or if you don't want to reboot just run command like in [similar question](https://serverfault.com/a/403745/157584).

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try clearing the cache and error reports i had about 5 gigs of such junk when i tried this first. I used [stacer](https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer/). You can do it manually also.

- install stacer `sudo apt install stacer`
- stacer is a gui application so you will know what to do.
  if you don't, launch stacer then click system cleaner (has broom icon on it) click select all then click the magnifying glass select stuff you want to delete then click broom icon again.

Answer (score 0):

When I need make more free space on servers I use this command. It find all files bigger then 50 MB and "du -h" make better list of files and "sort -n" after pipe make list numericcaly sorted by file size.

```
find / -size +50M -type f -exec du -h {} \; | sort -n
```

Comment: You'd be better off dust using `ncdu /` instead

Comment: Given `du -h`, use `sort -h` as well.