# How do I remove cached .deb files?

Tags: package-management, apt

I think once we get the packages with apt-get it stores in /var/cache/apt/archives . Is it safe to remove the archives files to save space? 
Can we remove other files as well to save some space?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I think it's safe to remove the archives files. So if you want to free up disk space this are my recommendations:

To delete downloaded packages (.deb) already installed (and no longer needed)

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

To remove all stored archives in your cache for packages that can not be downloaded anymore (thus packages that are no longer in the repository or that have a newer version in the repository).

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

To remove unnecessary packages (After uninstalling an app there could be packages you don't need anymore).

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To delete old kernel versions

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-X.X.XX-XX-generic
```

If you don't know which kernel version to remove

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image
```

**Source:** [Limpiando Ubuntu: comandos y programas (actualización)](http://www.glatelier.org/2010/10/limpiando-ubuntu-comandos-y-programas/) & [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space/)

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Curiously though, have you even had the need to go on to an older kernel version? I did a couple of times between 2005 and 2009 but not lately.

Comment: I found `apt-get --purge autoremove` at http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-delete-old-kernel-images-command/ which you can use to remove old linux kernel images

Comment: @itsols I have to revert a kernel a few days ago, a laptop would not boot with the new kernel.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is generally safe to remove them, unless you had a bad Internet connection and you needed to reinstall certain packages.

To remove them, open a terminal and type:

`sudo apt-get clean`

You can also use [Ubuntu-tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) and [Bleachbit](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 6):

And related at the clean cache... you can use this command

```
sudo dpkg --purge `COLUMNS=300 dpkg -l "*" | egrep "^rc" | cut -d\  -f3`
```

in order to delete all configuration related to unistalled program.

And:

1) *localepurge*: for delete localizazion packages not interested for you

2) *deporphan* and his gnome interface *gtkorphan*.

Comment: egrep appears to be deprecated nowadays; it can be replaced by "grep -E"

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can run 'sudo apt-get clean' to clean out any cached .debs.  If they're needed, they will be downloaded again.  There's also a program called computer-janitor to help with removing old files.

Comment: Hum... the point here is setting a flag that disables .DEB caching one and for all... if that is really available, doing anything else (crons to delete old files, etc) sounds like reinventing the wheel to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you messed around with installing partial packages then "apt-get autoclean" removes them too.

I run a Cron job to do this on some systems backed up to the Cloud to keep file sizes down.

HTH,

JR

Answer (score 0):

According to this : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28502/how-to-free-up-a-lot-of-disk-space-on-ubuntu-linux-by-deleting-cached-package-files/
there is an option to disable caching in synaptic package manager...

Does anyone know where is the configuration being defined?
(no where in /etc/apt/ as far as I can tell)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Additionally please use the Post answer button only for actual answers, if you have a question, add it either as a comment to your answer or the original question.

Comment: Sorry for that, but some how I missed the "add comment" link (have the feeling it was not there and I added an answer) until it was too late... be careful next time.