# Which folders I can delete to free HDD space in Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space)

Can I delete /usr/share/doc ? Which system files I can safely delete to free HDD space ?
Im running out of space (only 1.9 GB left). I have Wubi Installation of Ubuntu 11.10.