# How to find large unwanted packages to uninstall to free space?

Tags: apt, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space)

My root partition is filling up.  Is there a tool or a good way to identify large packages or collections of interdependent packages that I could remove to free space?