# How to disable low disk space notification?

Tags: gnome, disk-usage

I've got an SSD drive for root and /home, and a larger HDD for storage. The storage disk is almost full, and there's a low disk space warning on startup. The warning doesn't have any "don't show again" option, only "ignore" and "examine". It also doesn't go away but sticks on the screen until the ignore button is clicked, so it's very annoying in addition to being competely unnecessary.

I tried unselecting the storage HDD in baobab's settings, but that didn't have any effect. I also tried gconf-editor, and looked for apps -> gnome_settings_daemon -> plugins -> housekeeping, but there is no "plugins" under "gnome_settings_daemon". Only "gtk-modules" and "keybindings".

Comment: Still no answer for newer Ubuntu Versions!

Comment: Try dconf-editor, I found it. Still, there is still warning in GDM that I cannot disable.

Answer (score 6):

Found via https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/881376

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping active false`

Comment: It's seems the key is no longer there. Key path seems to be now `apps.gnome_settings_daemon.plugins.housekeeping`, but there's no key active (indeed there are any key). I created it and it doesn't work. I created also `free_size_gb_no_notify` and it also doesn't work. I'm using gnome 3.26.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

There is a option in dconf-editor that appears to allow you to select ignore paths that run low on space here:
`org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins > housekeeping > ignore-paths`
it takes a string array as an argument.

However, it seems to not do anything when I put the volume path using the following versions.
Gnome 40
dconf-editor 3.38.3

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

Got to `Settings` -> `Applications`. In the search box, type `disk`.
Click on `Disk Usage Analyser`. Next, click on the `Notifications` toggle switch to turn it off.

[image: screenshot (Gnome 43.3)]

Here is my SW versions:

```
$ uname -v
#40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Sep 18 02:14:19 UTC 2021

$ cat /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml; echo
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gnome-version>
 <platform>3</platform>
 <minor>36</minor>
 <micro>8</micro>
 <distributor>Ubuntu</distributor>
 <!--<date></date>-->
</gnome-version>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Disable low disk space warning with `gsettings`

The notification can be turned off for a specific path (mount point of partition) with this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping ignore-paths "['/my/mount/path/to/ignore']"
```

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/881376/comments/26)

---

##### Show description of `ignore-paths`

```
gsettings describe org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping ignore-paths
```

> Specify a list of mount paths to ignore when they run low on space.

---

##### Show more settings for low disk space warning (and their values)

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep housekeeping
```

---

Gnome Version: 43.1
GSettings Version: 2.74.1

Answer (score -4):

First check your free space with `df -h`

This answer will not try to stop the warning, but maybe you are better off, freeing some space, for example you can free space used by apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to free space, and I doubt apt-get would free space on the storage drive anyway

Comment: Here I created a script to uninstall more useless stuff: https://askubuntu.com/a/576431/34298