# What should I do when I lack space to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 12.10, version-upgrade

Could you help me? I was trying to upgrade my Compaq 510 from 12.04 to 12.10. But unfortunately the upgrade fails because I don't have enough free space for the temporary files. 
Could you tell me how to make room for the upgrade?

On Windows, you would use Disk Cleanup to empty some space.
But how can I do this on Ubuntu? Is there an app that works the same way?

There's so much app in Windows 7 & Ubuntu and then, this time it's left 1 GB With total around 74 GB if not wrong. Except D:/ (DATA) partition Total 160 GB. Please Think The C:/ (system) partition.

Comment: Hello Joel, thank you for your question. Could you please edit your question to be a little more precise : how much space do you already use ? How much space do you have left ? Is your drive partitioned ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I free up disk space?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space)

Answer (score 3):

To clean your system up and find some additional space, you may try to use [BleachBit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bleachbit/). It removes many unnecessary files in an excellent manner.

Comment: Make sure you clean your apt cache.  According to the BleachBit website, the program can handle it.  Otherwise, just type `sudo apt-get clean` in the Terminal.  You'd be surprised how much space is used up in the apt cache!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your system partition it might help to reduce the system reserved space from 5% to 0.5%.

`tune2fs -m .5 $devicename`

Should be the command but you should check the man page for more details. (Sorry I am currently writing from my phone)