# safemode how long should it take clean and free up space

Tags: startup

I now have a window that reads:

```
Continuing will remount your  / fillesystem in read/write mode and mount any other filesystem defined in /ect/fstab. Do you wish to continue ?
```

I replied Yes  and now I have under it:

```
  fsck from util-linux 2.20.1 /dev/sda: clean 318818/10117120 files, 24047888/40467456 blocks .
```

It been like this for 3 hours how should it take?

Comment: Is there a prompt below? How is it a Window? It should be shown on a console.

Comment: Yes it is in consol ,just a flashing cursor

Answer (score 0):

Once you get this second message you quoted the file system is already clean and you should be able to reboot (assuming the system doesn't go on to reboot.) That's why the word *clean* appears in that message.

This doesn't necessarily mean space is being freed--though a little bit could be freed should you have been writing to a file and your system crashed before the program was able to close the file. If you are running low on space there are other alternatives to tidy things up, such as those in  [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space) question.

For an ext2 or an ext3 system fsck normally takes a couple of minutes or less, but it depends on the size of the partition being checked. An advantage of ext4 is that fsck can run even faster there.