# The system is running in low-graphics mode error in "Virtualbox"

Tags: virtualbox

I faced a "The system is running in low-graphics mode error" like the on in this question [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

This happened in Virtualbox!

I'll go with the answer that the root file system ran out of space since I left the system downloading some stuff & previously I was notified that the system is low on space. Dumb of me but everyone makes mistakes. I was planning on moving the files to a shared folder later on.

The screen I get is similar to the screen in the link above. If I click on Ok, I get the following screen

[image]

None of the options work. I even tried to use the shell mode to try to free some space but all I get is this screen

[image]

So **my question is** how can I get back to my system & move the files to the shared folder (which btw needs guest additions which is was already installed on the system!) or better (if easier) an USB?

Note: I tried a live mode (iso) but I cannot do anything (e. G; open nautilus or a terminal!); + I get a VERP_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED_error when try to install guest additions.

Comment: I encountered this error immediately after installing guest additions under vbox 4.2.12.  Reverting to 4.2.10 fixes it.  I suggest saving state just before upgrading guest additions with each new vbox release.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Virtual Box Ubuntu behaves very similar to Ubuntu on bare metal. Therefore the solutions from this question

- [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

mostly hold true as well. However note, that you do not have a graphics card or proprietary drivers in a VM. This will all be handled by the guest additions.

We can enter a TTY for command line repair by press and hold the <kbd>HOST</kbd>-key, which in your case is the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-key and simultanously press <kbd>F1</kbd> trough <kbd>F8</kbd>.

In case your virtual hard drive runs short of memory try first with

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

to remove no longer needed packages. See also:

- [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space)

Comment: Thanks for the TTY thing :)

cleared 135+ MB due to a kernel upgrade! :)

I was able to log in & after re-enabling guest additions (I removed them when troubleshooting) & rebooted & I was able to access my files & move them (2.5GB).

The system is back & running. Thanks :)

Answer (score 22):

I just had the same error with a fresh installed ubuntu 12.04.2 that where just downloaded as well.

Just updating the system was enough for me:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: your solution has worked for me. thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Answer (score 12):

I just recently tried my hand at Ubuntu in VirtualBox and received the same error. For me, the solution was installing the VirtualBox Guest Additions. I followed the instructions [listed here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html), which are essentially:

1. Before installing the Guest Additions, you will have to prepare your guest system for building external kernel modules:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dkms
   ```
2. Insert the `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` CD file into your Linux guest's virtual CD-ROM drive and mount the ISO for the guest additions (it can be found in the VirtualBox installation directory):

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/cdrom /cdrom
   ```
3. Change to the directory where your CD-ROM drive is mounted and execute as root:

   ```
   sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
   ```

However, it has been a decade since I used Linux, so I had a little trouble finding out where the CD was mounted. I found a [post on the VirtualBox forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=34281) that gave me the nudge I needed to setup the mount point for the CD, then I was off and running.

Comment: +1 Perfectly solved the problem. By the way, Guest Additions can also be found at: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/. They are located in the respective VirtualBox version folders. Make sure to download the one that matches your respective VirtualBox version.

Answer (score 2):

My host machine is a Windows machine which has an ATI graphic card. The following procedure worked for me:

When the message that "your system is running in low-graphics mode" appears
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to enter the termina. Then login with your credentials, and then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx    
sudo reboot
```

This was an answer [posted in another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turns out I had accidentally edited the file `/etc/environment`.

#### To fix this:

1. Login with sudo command permission.
2. Edit the file using nano editor.
3. Make sure that there is no illegal entries in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: I recommend expanding this a bit, as it's unclear what "Login with sudo command permission" means.

Comment: More unclear as to the context of accidentally editing `/etc/environment` and how others would do that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing a 32 bit VirtualBox guest in a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 desktop machine.

64 bit guests in the same environment causes no problems, but the 32 bit guest got the low graphics warning.

The problem seems to be a bug in the display mechanism in the code on the Ubuntu 12.04 CD.

After I logged in through a TTY and did

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

everything works fine.

Hopefully, this will work out of the box with the next service release og 12.04.