# Revert upgrade in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

My Ubuntu 12.04 did some "unattended-upgrades" by itself and increased too much disk space. How can I revert this?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling security updates will unnecessarily expose your server to known and published security risks.

> [It is therefore strongly recommended to always install security updates.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/UpdateProcedures)

To clean up hard disk space after having installed these updates there are much better methods as outlined here:

- [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space)