# Refresh linux kernels list

Tags: 12.04

In boot directory I have a lot of files from previous versions. Is there a simple way to remove not currently used versions?

When I install updates I cannot see newly updated linux versions in grub menu. How can I refresh/reconfigure grub list to see allways lates linux versions?

Comment: `sudo update-grub` will update the grub menu, i use `synaptic` and filter to the kernel version and remove the 4 items for each old kernel, filter using version number

Comment: Please visit http://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space/6002#6002 for information on how to remove old kernels.