# Is it safe to delete documentation files?

Tags: root

I have to maintain 2gb on the root installation of ubuntu. The `home` is in another partition. I am thinking to delete the `/usr/share/doc` to free some space, but is it safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, No with a 'but'; it's always best to allow the built-in packaging system (APT) to manage files that it has installed. If you just delete these files, they'll probably reappear the next time you upgrade any of the affected packages, unexpectedly evaporating your space savings. Instead, use Software Center (or apt-get or aptitude) to remove the packages themselves. Usually they have the same name as the folder you see in `/usr/share/doc`, but if there's a folder that you can't figure out, try `dpkg -S /path/to/file`.

For example, after reading your question, I ran `ncdu /usr/share/doc` and found it was 1.7G, and most of the heavy hitters were related to texlive, which I only installed to check something for another AskUbuntu question. I ran aptitude, searched for packages matching ^texlive.*doc$, and purged them, and now it's down under 930M.

Answer (score 0):

My `/doc/` directory is very small, less than 50 MB, and I imagine yours isn't quite that large (in comparison) either.

Instead, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space) post on how to free up disk space in many different ways.  Lots of good suggestions there, but please keep in mind that some of those offer no way to 'back out' if something goes wrong.