# Ubuntu missing from boot menu

Tags: grub2

I recently dual booted Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04, both UEFI. When I boot, I get directly to Windows 8, without any prompt or boot menu/grub menu. To access Ubuntu, I have to go to boot options by pressing `F-12` while booting. How do I get the boot menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a problem of broken grub. Grub is basically a boot loader. In other words it is the screen that comes up with options to start Windows or Ubuntu.  I had a very similar problem. In my case I had dual booted Mint and Ubuntu. To fix the grub, check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: Yup! I got the grub menu alright, but now there is a new problem. I have 5 options, namely: 'Ubuntu', 'Advanced Options for Ubuntu', 'Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi', 'Windows boot UEFI loader' and 'System Setup'. Now, when I hit enter for Ubuntu, its all right, but when I go for Windows Boot EFI loader, the system goes for a restart. Why is it so?

Comment: See if [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager) helps.

Comment: Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) official Ubuntu help page. It closely relates to your problem.