# usr/bin/x11 replication is eating up space, how do I correct this?

Tags: 12.04

The replication of `/usr/bin/x11` is eating up disk space. How do I correct this?  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Dell Mini9 with a 8gb HD.

The file x11 is replicating.  Every time I open one there is another x11, each w/1461 items.  I gave up looking after 24 occurrences.  The file USR is using 3.2gb. I tried installing ubuntu 13.04, but there not enough space to finish the install.

Comment: Could you clarify what replication are you referring to? Did you start it yourself or itself?

Answer (score 0):

You won't save more than a few bytes by removing `/usr/bin/X11` because it is a symbolic link to the `/usr/bin` directory:

```
$ ls -l X11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1 Sep  9  2011 X11 -> .
$ readlink -f X11
/usr/bin
```

In order to actually free up some space, see also [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5980/6969)