# How to clean /var/cache?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, cache, cleanup, polipo

When I woke up this morning, I found my root had filled overnight

```
du -hx --max-depth=1 /

132M    /boot  
4.0K    /media  
16K /lost+found  
16M /root  
702M    /lib  
4.0K    /OLDHOME  
8.2G    /usr  
73M /etc  
4.0K    /srv  
11M /sbin  
4.0K    /selinux  
8.0K    /.config  
4.0K    /cdrom  
4.6G    /var  
181M    /opt  
4.0K    /mnt  
9.3M    /bin  
4.0K    /lib64  
14G /
```

The space is used by /var/cache/polipo (2.7G). How can I clean this up safely?
I tried restarts=>didn't work
Used bleachbit=>the space is not detected in the cleanup preview

PS: I did rm -rf *youtube* inside /var/cache/polipo and it freed up 2G space. Dunno if it was safe though

Comment: whats that polipo ?

Comment: polipo is a caching proxy

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Polipo, a web caching program may store a lot of data in an on-disk cache.

One way to clear this up is to issue the command `sudo polipo -x` - this will cause polipo to clear the local disk cache.

Comment: This is the ONLY right answer to this question (regarding polipo)! Why the hell does it not already have enough votes to make that clear?!?

Answer (score 70):

Method 1:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Method 2:

Launch your bleachbit as root user : [no space in disk; sudo apt-get clean not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367348/no-space-in-disk-sudo-apt-get-clean-not-working/367356#367356)

Comment: All these were already done. The problem is in /var/cache. I want to know how to clean /var/cache safely.

Comment: went from 500M to 300M but somehow not everything...hmm...

Answer (score 16):

The most powerful of all commands to clean the cache for command line users is of course

```
sudo apt clean
```

Which will also delete all the cached files.

Comment: I don't know what this command did but it didn't clear /var/cache, space is nearly double after I ran it!

Comment: This command will only delete the apt cache from `/var/cache/apt`.

Answer (score 5):

Try cleaning ubuntu unnecesarry files using [bleachbit](http://bleachbit.com/).
It is a tool that will help you clean your cache, temp files, cookies and it has other features also...

To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

Comment: Unfortunately it appears to be an X windows app, any love for us server command line folk?

Comment: yes that will work when your disk is full...

Answer (score 5):

It sounds so obvious, and yet chances are you haven’t done this.

By default Ubuntu keeps every update it downloads and installs in a cache on your disk, just in case you ever need it again.

This is useful if you regularly add and remove apps, find yourself needing to reconfigure/reinstall a specific package, or simply have a poor connection.

But the flip side is that the apt package cache can quickly swell to several hundred MBs. This command tells you how big your apt cache is:

```
du -sh /var/cache/apt/archives
```

To clean the apt cache on Ubuntu simply run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

The apt clean command removes ALL packages kept in the apt cache, regardless of age or need. If you’re on a slow, capped or intermittent connection you may want to consider skipping this step.

[Source](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/5-ways-free-up-space-on-ubuntu).

Comment: It is all true what you say but the OP wrote _"The space is used by /var/cache/polipo (2.7G)"_

Answer (score 1):

Go to **settings** > privacy > File history & Trash scroll down and click delete *temporary files*.