# How to find the biggest directories in my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I logged into my server this morning and received a `disk is full` error. How do I fix this or find wherever all of this data is hiding?

Comment: You fix it by either deleting necessary files or making the partitions larger. Start by looking at large files you might have in your home directory.

Comment: I already posted the answer Bodhi. =] And sometimes you can't make the partitions larger, and sometimes the home folders are empty.

Comment: check this out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space/6014#6014

Comment: @jet the `sort` command needs free disk space. If you don't have that, it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing you want to do is try to login as root (recovery mode).

EDIT: If you are in recovery mode, you'll need to remount as RW. To do this, `mount -o remount,rw /`.

Run `cd /`. This allows you to enter the root and begin to trace the problem.

When you are in `/`, run `du -sh *`. This'll give you a list of all of the files in your hard drive. Let's say you  see

```
2.6T var
```

You know that the problem is in `/var`. You then `cd /var` and run the `du -sh *` command again. Scroll and look for something like

```
2.6T zpanel
```

You then know the problem is in the ZPanel folder. (I am using ZPanel for this example, as I just recovered from this exact problem). By now you know the drill. You `cd zpanel/`  and `du -sh *`. Look for something like

```
2.6T backups
```

Same old, same old. `cd backups/`, `du -sh *`. But this time, you get

```
(size) zpanel_date_etc
```

The `backups` folder contains no more subdirectories, so you expunge the unnecessary files. In my case, I used `rm -rf zpanel_*` and went from 100% capacity to 25% capacity.

Then, you fix wherever the problem is. (For me, it's in ZPanel's backup settings, so I should change those).

This works with any situation, all you need to do is trace the problem.

N.B. I know you could have probably used a `sort` to do this, but if you have no temp space, you can't `sort`. This is the best option.