# No space for ubuntu to load

Tags: boot, partitioning, disk-usage

Help! I have Ubuntu 14.04 dual booted with Windows 7, I was using Ubuntu and writing files from one drive to another, however I didnt realise that I would soon run out of disk space on my laptop hard drive (the destination for the copy). I left the copy to it and came back to a message saying that my disk space was low. I cancelled the copy and got to a command line, moved the files to an external drive so they were off the laptop drive. However, I rebooted and Ubuntu wouldnt get passed the splash screen.

I edited the advanced options in Grub and got a text login screen. I logged in and can see my directories. I ran

```
df -h
```

and can see that /dev/sda5 shows as 100% used and no free space. I cant work this out, as I moved all the files, so are they stuck in a tmp directory somewhere?

I tried

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and that didnt help matters. I deleted some files from my downloads folder (there wasnt much in there to begin with, but some large files) and I've freed up about 45M.

Anywhere else I should be looking. I've tried a few commands to search for large files...

```
sudo find / -size +50M -ls
```

but its not showing anything of significance. Any help appreciated.

Edit:

Full output of df -h and fdisk -l as follows:
[image]

Comment: What is the complete output of `df -h` and `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: updated with pic - apols its not plaintext, its on the laptop and i'm using another pc to post this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow this in recovery mode:

[How to find the biggest directories in my hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397842/how-to-find-the-biggest-directories-in-my-hard-drive)

It will help you find big files/folders and clean stuff up.

Comment: this is awesome, thanks Mew. The issue was in my home folder, as expected and I found some weird, large files (+1GB) so removed those and things looking as expected now. Top stuff, I've favourite that link for future