# Clear .cache Tracker directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: cache, tracker

I created a partition for Ubuntu, and I just ran out of space a couple of days ago.

I used the *Disk Usage Analyzer* and I realized that for some reason the directory `/home/.cache` uses up a lot of disk space; specifically the `tracker` folder. What is recommended to do in order to prevent this cache and tracker folder to grow so much?

Comment: If you want to disable the tracker completely, I suggest this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72827703/how-to-disable-file-indexing-in-ubuntu-22-04-tracker3#73197441

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can "pause" the Gnome Tracker by setting the configuration option `org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files.low-disk-space-limit` used by `tracker-miner-fs`.

Values indicate if we pause indexing at a percentage of low disk space (0-100% or -1 to disable the check entirely, 3 being the default value).

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type the following command to stop the tracker at 1%:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files low-disk-space-limit 1
```

[Source](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/Configuration).

Comment: Does this mean that the tracker pauses when only 1% of disk space remains or when the tracker files take up 1% of disk space?

Comment: From the horses mouth: "Values indicate if we pause indexing at *a percentage of low disk space*"