# How much cache is tracker supposed to use?

Tags: tracker

Tracker uses a lot of memory/CPU and has at least 22GB of cache on my harddrive. How much cache is tracker supposed to use?

Comment: Cache? As much as it can.

Comment: So, admittedly a different question,  is there a way of limiting it @muru. I am getting low on disk space because of it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/465215/158442?

Comment: @muru transform two comments into an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear .cache Tracker directory in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465036/clear-cache-tracker-directory-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default is no limit to the amount of cache tracker will use, but you can set a limit as per https://askubuntu.com/a/465215/115155.

Credit to [@muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru)

Comment: Oh, yeah, forgot about this. :)