# When is it safe to delete the contents of /tmp and /var/tmp?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, delete, rm, tmp

I'm trying to make a locked down, auto-restoring system that will restore itself once every week. I'm wondering if /tmp and /var/tmp can be safely removed if the system is booted on a different partition (e.g. /dev/sda1 is mounted as the filesystem root and /dev/sda2 is mounted on /mnt, so would it be safe to remove /mnt/tmp and /mnt/var/tmp?).

I've tried searching for answers on this, but I've only found people asking if it's safe to delete when it is actively in use which I already know it is not.

Comment: Okay, so if it is supposed to be cleared on reboot anyway, it should be safe to clear manually and then boot back into the system.

Comment: @ThomasWard `/var/tmp` is not cleared on boot, it's supposed to persist across reboots. Only `/tmp` is cleared on boot. See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/864383/is-it-safe-to-delete-files-from-var-tmp

Comment: @ByteCommander note the "Assuming they're identical" portions of mycomments.  :P

Comment: @user806799 You should not be touching `/var/tmp`, apparently.

Comment: Alright, I'll leave /var/tmp alone for now, but would it be safe to restore it on a daily basis as an alternative? I see systemd and kdecache files in my current one. I'll give that a try at some point and post on here how it goes.