# How to clean cache and orphan dependencies in snap and flatpak?

Tags: snap, disk-usage, cache, flatpak

Is there an equivalent of `sudo apt clean` in snap and flatpak (to delete the cached installation files)?

That might free up a considerable amount of space.

Also, is there any equivalent of `sudo apt autoremove`, or is it taken care of automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not come across one but the following should help:

### Snapd

Snap generally preserves at least three revisions (older versions) of any software / package you have installed at any point of time. This makes snapd/cache very bulky. You can set to 1 or 2 using

```
sudo snap set system refresh.retain=2  // starting from snapd version 2.34
```

This way you preserver lot of space. Now, clearing the cached installation

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/snapd
```

### flatpak

The analogous process of `sudo apt autoremove` in flatpak is

```
flatpak uninstall --unused
```

Comment: Even after that [flatpak still use](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/1119) a considerable space (`du -hc /var/tmp/flatpak-cache-* | tail -1`). [Probably safe to delete](https://askubuntu.com/a/864398/349837) anyway.

Comment: For snap, `refresh.retain=1` isn't allowed (`retain must be a number between 2 and 20, not "1"`), and 2 can still be incredibly bulky. Also, changing the setting doesn't immediately free any space. You need to manually [remove old versions](https://superuser.com/questions/1310825/how-to-remove-old-version-of-installed-snaps).