# How to free disk space from snaps

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, snap, disk-usage

I would like to free up space in my hard disk. Since the snaps take up a lot of space I pruned the unused ones (see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036633/how-to-remove-disabled-unused-snap-packages-with-a-single-line-of-command?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top))

Now I have this:
[image]

but the directory content is:
[image]

Why do I have 6 snaps of firefox? By the way the one listed by snap doesn't even turn out to be the most recent.
How do I clean up the /var/lib/snapd/snaps directory, to leave just the bare minimum there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clean cache and orphan dependencies in snap and flatpak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228432/how-to-clean-cache-and-orphan-dependencies-in-snap-and-flatpak) This question answers how to free up disk space occupied by old snap packages as well as snap cache

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Unfortunately, no, I have performed the steps described in the post, none of which act directly on the directory containing the snaps, which in fact is unchanged. I still have 6 files for firefox

Answer (score -1):

You can install Stacer and try to use it. It's a system optimization tool and it works well for me!

Comment: you should try to improve your answer by being more specific about which options to use in `Stacer` and include how to install the tool. Perhaps even a screenshot of the chosen option will help too.