How can i remove cookies files from the var/tmp folder?
I am new to Ubuntu , I have a VPS server that uses Ubuntu and WHM to manage Cpanel reseller accounts , i have some php services stopped due to var/tmp folder is full.
I ran du command to check the files on that directory and found 235000 cookies files on it
like this:
error: Failed to lstat() `/tmp/rdweb_cookie_file_g0SVqE': Structure needs cleaning

and some other empty directories.
So is it safe to remove these files? if so can i have the proper command to remove these cookies files only ?

EDIT :
What i need is a safe, direct, command line to remove all the cookies files only inside the var/temp directory , that will not destroy anything.
*** EDIT 2 ***
Ubuntu version: 20.04.6 LTS

Please edit the question and put in the info on the other directories.

What version and type of Ubuntu?

well as i mentioned , i am new to Ubuntu , so can you advice how and where to get these info ?

You do not know what you installed? What was the name of the ISO that will be the name of the version and type.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

@stumblebee , thanks for your guidance , i updated the post with the version , the version is : 20.04.6 LTS

See this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/864383/is-it-safe-to-delete-files-from-var-tmp

I have searched the [ error +"structure needs cleaning" ] text, and had found that it is neither specific to cookie files, nor to temporary files. Instead, it seems to indicate filesystem corruption. See this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/330742

That means that you will need to find a way to access the problematic physical disk partition while it's not in use ("unmounted"), and then run the fsck (filesystem check) utility program on it, to let it fix the errors. Luckily the error is among tmp files, so apparently you don't have to worry about making backups. Accessing a physical system partition while it is not in use can be done by powering down the system, then booting from an Ubuntu "live" installer USB (in "try Ubuntu" mode), locating the partition in question, and running fsck on it.

@Levente thanks for clarification , yes i can't remove the files , i will go through the filesystem check.

This may offer further insight: https://superuser.com/a/1243827
