# Low Diskspace warning when almost 500G is on another HDD

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, hard-drive

[image: Disk Usage Analyzer]

I also got gparted:

on this one there is almost 500GB
[image: 500GB]

Here is the culprit:
[image: 16GB cap]

Here is some more data

```
➜  ~ df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  9.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1      ext4       15G   14G  240M  99% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.7G  110M  7.6G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     squashfs  4.4M  4.4M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/15
/dev/loop2     squashfs  4.4M  4.4M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/17
/dev/loop1     squashfs   75M   75M     0 100% /snap/ubuntu-core/423
/dev/sda5      ext4      444G   13G  409G   3% /home
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G   68K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop3     squashfs  4.4M  4.4M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/22
/dev/loop4     squashfs   76M   76M     0 100% /snap/ubuntu-core/1797


➜  ~ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8042684k,nr_inodes=2010671,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1612560k,mode=755)
/dev/sdb1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=34,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_15.snap on /snap/canonical-livepatch/15 type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_17.snap on /snap/canonical-livepatch/17 type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/ubuntu-core_423.snap on /snap/ubuntu-core/423 type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/dev/sda5 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1612560k,mode=755)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/canonical-livepatch.mnt type nsfs (rw)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1612560k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
/dev/sdb1 on /var/lib/docker/aufs type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_22.snap on /snap/canonical-livepatch/22 type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/ubuntu-core_1797.snap on /snap/ubuntu-core/1797 type squashfs (ro,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)

➜  ~ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST500LM021-1KJ15 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 2      1048kB  484GB  484GB   extended
 5      1049kB  484GB  484GB   logical   ext4
 1      484GB   500GB  16.4GB  primary   linux-swap(v1)


Model: ATA SanDisk SSD U110 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  16.0GB  16.0GB  primary  ext4         boot
```

So looks like I have a lot of space thats not being used?

Comment: Your root partition is only 16GB, that is really small, try free up some space. Here I created a script to uninstall useless stuff: https://askubuntu.com/a/576431/34298

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here...

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      ext4       15G   14G  240M  99% /
```

your / partition is full... well, the real problem is that your / partition is too small. It's too small of a SSD for this. Ubuntu / partitions should be no smaller than 20G, and 30-60G is more realistic. You can probably get rid of some old Ubuntu kernels in `/boot`, and if you search here on Ask Ubuntu, you'll find plenty of instructions on how to best do that.

Another idea would be to build a bootable system on the 500G and use the 16G SSD for something else.