# Want to make space on my computer, show installed apps I don't need and can remove

Tags: dpkg, uninstall

Please can you tell me how to see what I have installed on my computer, so that I can make a judgement call to remove some of the unnecessary programs.  I tried the following code    dpkg -l | grep ii however the number of installed programs just whizzes through the screen so fast.  Is there any way of halting it, or scrolling through the list.  Each up and down arrow I press simply shows me my previous commands.

Then I would like some recommendations of what to remove.

Thanks in advance.
Vince.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space for useful information. Because of so many shared libraried (=package dependencies) deleting a single application urually will free very little space, and removing a seeminly unimportant package can result in unwanted wiping of most of Ubuntu.

Comment: Where on your disk are you out of space ? Please update your question with the output of `df -h`

Comment: FWIW it is typically easier to do a minimal install and build up rather than remove packages. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD . If you do remove packages use the --purge option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use less.

```
dpkg -l | grep ii | less
```

to halt the scrolling.

Comment: Thanks Bruni, that works.  So, what Takkat is saying is to be careful what I remove.  What command do I use to see how much disk space is actually used?

Comment: That would be df -h as suggested by @Soren A

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer, you can use [Synaptic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/synaptic/) to view what programs you have installed.

If it's not present, you can install it by `sudo apt install synaptic`.

Go to Settings > Filter. At Search Filter option, Deselect All and choose "Installed" and "Residual config".
[image]

So you can choose what you want to Mark for Complete Removal.

Comment: I can't install that Redbob.  I'm running 16:04 server, not the visual version.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it, as you didn't detailed it at your question.