# apt-get -f install problem

Tags: apt

I'm getting this error on my AWS Ubuntu t2 micro. I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux. While installing nodejs package, it recommended I run `sudo apt-get -f install`. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 183 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/816 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,473 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 505710 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-119.143_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-119.143_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic/include/config/ring/buffer/allow/swap.h.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic/include/config/ring/buffer/allow/swap.h'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-119.143_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: *"No space left on device"* - you will need to free up some disk space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not directly related to the command `apt-get -f install`. As the error message indicates your system does not have any free space left to install packages.

Check [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space) to find some ideas how to clean up.