# How to easily remove old kernels in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: kernel, software-uninstall

I have old Linux kernel versions that I don't use so I was trying to remove them.

List of installed kernels from `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`

```
linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic (5.4.0-26.30)   
linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic (5.4.0-33.37)
linux-image-5.4.0-37-generic (5.4.0-37.41)
```

Comment: Does `sudo apt autoremove` help? Which kernels are you asking about?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt autoremove`? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1253347/edit) your question and add all the new information. Also indicate if you installed the kernels manually or something special.

Comment: These are regular Ubuntu kernels. `autoremove` should remove them.

Comment: Hmmm. Show us complete output. `dpkg --list` output includes kernels that *have already been removed*. The first column will indicate which packages are removed (`rc`) and which are installed (`ii`).

Comment: There are a couple of excellent kernel removal manager type scripts around. I used the server version from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu/892096#892096), for a long time, but now use [this one](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge). Note that I can not use autoremove, as it misbehaves when one uses mainline kernels. The manual method becomes tedious when trying to clean up 100 kernels.

Comment: For me, the system updater removes them automatically sometime after installing new kernel version.

Comment: If you googled here it's probably some bug of synaptic. I get an error when try to remove an old kernel version with synaptic, but removing it with apt purge works.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here are the steps to remove unused kernels.

Check what current kernel You run:

```
uname -a
Linux blackhole 5.6.13-050613-lowlatency #202005141310 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 14 13:17:41 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am running `5.6.13-050613-lowlatency`

List all installed kernels in Your OS:

```
dpkg --list | egrep -i --color 'linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules' | awk '{ print $2 }'
linux-headers-5.6.11-050611
linux-headers-5.6.11-050611-lowlatency
linux-headers-5.6.13-050613
linux-headers-5.6.13-050613-lowlatency
linux-image-unsigned-5.6.11-050611-lowlatency
linux-image-unsigned-5.6.13-050613-lowlatency
linux-modules-5.6.11-050611-lowlatency
linux-modules-5.6.13-050613-lowlatency
```

Uninstall kernels You don't need:

```
sudo apt purge linux-headers-5.6.11-050611  linux-headers-5.6.11-050611-lowlatency linux-image-unsigned-5.6.11-050611-lowlatency linux-modules-5.6.11-050611-lowlatency
```

Comment: *dpkg --list | egrep -i --color 'linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules' | awk '{ print $2 }'*. Really? Doesn't `ls -1 /boot/vm*` list your kernels including the current one?

Comment: @PaulBenson Your command does not list packages. So You can't use these names in `apt` or `dpkg` to uninstall kernels.

Comment: Isn't there an automated way to do that? I have more than 50 kernels installed in the list, many with `un` tag.

Comment: While this seems tedious, it appears to be the only viable way. I would have loved to do it automatically, but I am unable to find a nice script for that. My hacky workaround is to use `sudo apt-get purge linux-*-*-5.*` (feel free to remove one `-*` to catch some other modules and do the same with `4.*`) and manually check the output. This will get the desired packages, but might be too aggressive - i.e. check the output carefully to avoid a system suicide.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, StackExchange won't let me edit the comment after the 5 min mark. I have found this nice script: https://www.tecmint.com/remove-old-kernel-in-debian-and-ubuntu/ (i.e. `purge-old-kernels` as a script included in the package `byobu`). This might help, but I have already purged all old kernels so can't test it for now.

Comment: Suppose I built and installed a newer kernel. I then boot under an older one and use this command. The new one is not listed, despite being listed in GRUB. Does this mean it didn't install properly? (I am troubleshooting issues with the new kernel not booting properly).

Comment: thanks. it worked for me

Comment: Shorthand (use at own risc!): sudo apt remove --purge $(dpkg --list | egrep -i --color 'linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules' |grep -v $(uname -r)| awk '{ print $2 }')

Answer (score 40):

You can try out this script

remove_old_kernels.sh

```shell
#!/bin/bash
# Run this script without any param for a dry run
# Run the script with root and with exec param for removing old kernels after checking
# the list printed in the dry run

uname -a
IN_USE=$(uname -a | awk '{ print $3 }')
echo "Your in use kernel is $IN_USE"

OLD_KERNELS=$(
    dpkg --list |
        grep -v "$IN_USE" |
        grep -Ei 'linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules' |
        awk '{ print $2 }'
)
echo "Old Kernels to be removed:"
echo "$OLD_KERNELS"

if [ "$1" == "exec" ]; then
    for PACKAGE in $OLD_KERNELS; do
        yes | apt purge "$PACKAGE"
    done
else
    echo "If all looks good, run it again like this: sudo remove_old_kernels.sh exec"
fi
```

Run it like this for a dry run:

```shell
remove_old_kernels.sh
```

If all looks good, run it again like this:

```shell
sudo remove_old_kernels.sh exec
```

Comment: Excellent, it worked perfect with PopOS 20.04

Comment: headers and modules are also getting deleted other than generic. How to handle that situation?

Comment: You can change the script to only `grep` for the `linux-image` if you really want to keep the others

Comment: Whenever I run this script, and it deletes an entry, I am getting stuck unable to press a selection on the menu about modifying grub files. Is there a way to go about fixing that? When I do manual delete of a kernel, I am able to make a selection in that menu to proceed.

Comment: Works like a charm on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This script has an issue, that it tries to remove the following packages:
- linux-headers-generic
- linux-image-generic

and my kernel is 5.17.5-76051705-generic, and it tried to remove linux-headers-5.17.5-76051705. I suppose it needs to filter out these packages as well.

Otherwise this is the perfect script! It removed a lot of old packages i had on my system. But sadly dpkg doesn't want to remove the directories of the modules...

Comment: why the loop? wouldn't this be more fitting? `apt purge "$PACKAGE" $OLD_KERNELS` then apt would remove them in one run and show how much space is freed summarized

Comment: I created an enhanced version of this script in https://github.com/rubo77/remove-old-kernels

Answer (score 13):

Just taking Michal's answer a little further. I didn't want to type the kernels to delete everytime so I decided to use files instead.

Write all the current kernels you have on a file.

```
dpkg --list | egrep -i --color 'linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules' | awk '{ print $2 }' > kernels.txt
```

Filter your currently used kernel out of the file using grep.

```
grep -v $(uname -r) kernels.txt > kernels_to_delete.txt
```

Verify your current kernel is not present in the delete list. Don't skip this. Ensures you don't mistakenly delete all the kernels.

```
grep $(uname -r) kernels_to_delete.txt
```

Delete all the unused kernels in one go.

```
cat kernels_to_delete.txt | xargs sudo apt purge -y
```

Answer (score 10):

An update to @alex Burdusel's script would be the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# Run this script without any arguments for a dry run
# Run the script with root and with exec arguments for removing old kernels and modules after checking
# the list printed in the dry run

uname -a
IN_USE=$(uname -a | awk '{ print $3 }')
echo "Your in use kernel is $IN_USE"

OLD_KERNELS=$(
    dpkg --get-selections |
        grep -v "linux-headers-generic" |
        grep -v "linux-image-generic" |
        grep -v "linux-image-generic" |
        grep -v "${IN_USE%%-generic}" |
        grep -Ei 'linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules' |
        awk '{ print $1 }'
)
echo "Old Kernels to be removed:"
echo "$OLD_KERNELS"

OLD_MODULES=$(
    ls /lib/modules |
    grep -v "${IN_USE%%-generic}" |
    grep -v "${IN_USE}"
)
echo "Old Modules to be removed:"
echo "$OLD_MODULES"

if [ "$1" == "exec" ]; then
  apt-get purge $OLD_KERNELS
  for module in $OLD_MODULES ; do
    rm -rf /lib/modules/$module/
  done
fi
```

This solves the issue that it tries to delete the following packages:

```
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-headers-5.17.5-76051705 # if 5.17.5-76051705-generic is the current kernel
```

This script was modified to purge all packages at once, and also delete any remaining module directories in /lib/modules/

Comment: I would add else; echo "call this script again with $0 exec to really uninstall those kernels"

Comment: like in https://github.com/rubo77/remove-old-kernels

Answer (score 7):

Just use this:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Comment: Note that this command won't remove older kernels only, but any package that is not needed as a dependency of other packages along with its configuration files.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog, sure, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It doesn't work for 20.04 (upgraded from 18.04, and upgraded from 16.04). I can list the packages, but ubuntu doesn't autoremove old kernels.

Comment: @gavioto20 strange, I also used Ubuntu 20.04 and this command did work for removing old kernels? It will only remove kernels that are not actively used.

Comment: FWIW, I was trying to run this command after installing a new kernel had failed because I was running out of space on `/boot`. Unfortunately, the command tried installing the new kernel again which… failed again – probably because it hadn't finished removing all those old images yet. :/ Ultimately I went with @eitch's script and this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

To easily remove older versions kernels, e.g. kernels starting from 4.0 and so on.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.*
```

Comment: Are you sure, that `linux-image-4.*` will remove "old" `linux-image-5.4.xxx` kernel images?

Comment: Ofcourse not, how do you expect that to remove kernels with a starting 5. You can update command accordingly. I just gave an example. For linux-image-5.4.xxx use `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.4.*` and so on.

Comment: You also have to do it for the headers: `sudo apt purge linux-headers-4.*`

Answer (score 1):

`autoremove` will only remove packages that are automatically installed. If you ever updated or added a kernel package manually `autoremove` will not remove it. If you ever "held" a kernel version `autoremove` will not remove it. If you're wondering why Ubuntu is filling up your boot partition with kernels you no longer use it's likely one of these two reasons.

```
# Unhold all packages
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold | awk '{ print $1, "install" }' | dpkg --set-selections

# Mark all "manually installed" kernel packages as "automatically installed"
for f in $(apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-); do
    apt-mark auto $f
done

# Remove all packages that are no longer needed
apt-get -y autoremove --purge
```

Answer (score 1):

I derived this script from previous answers.
It should reserve the current kernel and one previous kernel.
As stated in previous answers, execute once without any arguments for a dry run.
Then run as root with 1 argument as 'exec' to actually remove the old kernels.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

IN_USE=$(uname -a | awk '{ print $3 }')
echo "Your in use kernel is $IN_USE"

CUR_KERNELS=$(dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image | grep install | awk '{print $1}')
echo
echo "Current Kernels are:"
echo "$CUR_KERNELS"

OLD_KERNELS=$(dpkg --get-selections | grep linux | grep deinstall | awk '{print $1}')
echo
echo "Old Kernels to be removed:"
echo "$OLD_KERNELS"

if [ "$1" == "exec" ]; then
  apt-get purge $OLD_KERNELS
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As for easy solution, use a utility called *linux-purge* that is made just for the purpose, and that is supposed to work by any release of Ubuntu later than 12.04. The utility is implemented using Bash.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1297443/21005) is my answer with more details to another similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Further improvement to the script:

Courtesy of @eitch

This version filters out the newer kernels. In earlier versions, the newer kernels will also get purged.

This script defaults to "dry-run" but if the $1 is anything other than "dry-run" or "exec" then the usage help text is displayed.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# Function to print usage instructions
print_usage() {
  echo "Usage: $0 [dry-run|exec]"
  echo "  dry-run: List old kernels and modules without removing them (default)"
  echo "  exec: Remove the listed old kernels and modules (requires root privileges)"
}

# Function to compare kernel version numbers
# Returns 1 if version1 is greater than version2, 0 if equal, and -1 if lesser
compare_versions() {
  local version1=(${1//./ })
  local version2=(${2//./ })

  for i in {0..2}; do
    if [[ ${version1[i]} -gt ${version2[i]} ]]; then
      return 1
    elif [[ ${version1[i]} -lt ${version2[i]} ]]; then
      return -1
    fi
  done

  return 0
}

# Check for valid input arguments
if [[ $# -gt 1 ]] || { [[ $# -eq 1 ]] && [[ "$1" != "dry-run" ]] && [[ "$1" != "exec" ]]; }; then
  print_usage
  exit 1
fi

# Display current running kernel
uname -a
IN_USE=$(uname -a | awk '{ print $3 }')
echo "Your in-use kernel is $IN_USE"

# Find old kernels
OLD_KERNELS=$(
  dpkg --get-selections |
  grep -v "linux-headers-generic" |
  grep -v "linux-image-generic" |
  grep -Ei 'linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules' |
  awk '{ print $1 }' |
  grep -v "${IN_USE}"
)

# Filter out newer kernels
FILTERED_KERNELS=""
for kernel in $OLD_KERNELS; do
  kernel_version=$(echo "$kernel" | grep -oP '(?<=linux-image-|linux-headers-|linux-modules-)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){0,2}' || true)
  if [[ ! -z "$kernel_version" ]]; then
    compare_versions "$kernel_version" "$IN_USE"
    if [[ $? -eq -1 ]]; then
      FILTERED_KERNELS+="$kernel"$'\n'
    fi
  else
    FILTERED_KERNELS+="$kernel"$'\n'
  fi
done
OLD_KERNELS="$FILTERED_KERNELS"

# Find old modules
OLD_MODULES=$(
  ls /lib/modules |
  grep -v "${IN_USE}" |
  while read -r module; do
    module_version=$(echo "$module" | grep -oP '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){0,2}' || true)
    if [[ ! -z "$module_version" ]]; then
      compare_versions "$module_version" "$IN_USE"
      if [[ $? -eq -1 ]]; then
        echo "$module"
      fi
    else
      echo "$module"
    fi
  done
)

# Display old kernels and modules
echo "Old Kernels to be removed:"
echo "$OLD_KERNELS"
echo "Old Modules to be removed:"
echo "$OLD_MODULES"

# Remove old kernels and modules if "exec" argument is passed
if [ "$1" == "exec" ]; then
  # Check for root privileges
  if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "Error:This operation requires root privileges. Please run the script as root or use 'sudo'."
    exit 1
  fi
  # Remove Old Kernel
  apt-get purge $OLD_KERNELS
  # Remove Old Modules
  for module in $OLD_MODULES ; do
    rm -rf /lib/modules/$module/
  done
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

Not one of these worked for me.

Had to use:

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux.modules-extra-5.4.0-84.94
```