# How to change the Ubuntu kernel version in grub's first menu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

**These helped me solve the problem:**

[How to easily remove old kernels in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253347/how-to-easily-remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts)

[How do stop Ubuntu 20.04 from upgrading to the 5.8 hwe kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306358/how-do-stop-ubuntu-20-04-from-upgrading-to-the-5-8-hwe-kernel)

**---------------------------------------------------**

In Grub menu, the Ubuntu option launches kernel version 5.8, that doesn't work for me (black screen). In advanced options for Ubuntu I have kernel versions 5.4 that work properly.

I want to change the launch options of the Ubuntu option to launch a 5.4 version by default, so I don't need to enter Advanced options for Ubuntu, to choose a 5.4 version every time I boot.
How do I do that?

**Edit_1:**

As you can see in Ubuntu parameters is the 5.8 version. I need somehow to change it to a 5.4 version that I can find in Advanced options for Ubuntu.

Ubuntu parameters from Grub2:

[image: Ubuntu parameters from Grub2]

**Edit_2**

[(1) Grub customizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boVEA.png)

[(2) Grub customizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKC4X.png)

How can I change the code from 2 picture to use the "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-59-generic", instead of "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-36-generic"?

**A potentialy bad solution:**

Created a new menuentry "Ubuntu_2" using the script of the menuentry "Ubuntu", and replaced the "linux" and "initrd" lines with the code from "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-59-generic".
It worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Comment: In your case removing the 5.8 kernel is a better idea.

Comment: @Pilot6 could you check my 'Edit_2' ?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Grub customizer helped a lot, so that answer helped partially.

Comment: I never use grub customizer. And this is not a good idea. Now the 5.4.0-60 kernel already came. Are you planning doing it all the time?

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't know. Actually all worked well since the 5.8 appeared and was used automatically by the "Ubuntu" mainentry from my Grub menu. I guess I'll stick with the 5.4.0.59 for an indefinite time.

Comment: Why not remove the 5.8 and stick with 5.4.0-xx with normal updates? And it not difficult to fix you black screen issue too, but some information is needed. So the question is a sort of [XY Pronlem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306358/how-do-stop-ubuntu-20-04-from-upgrading-to-the-5-8-hwe-kernel

Comment: @karel I don't know how to set up correctly priority files in /etc/apt/preferences, but I did remove HWE meta packages (Thanks to Pilot6 reply), so I think that solved the problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks. That helped me a lot.