# System doesn't boot after adding user to group with gpasswd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, user-management

I ran

```
sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
```

I have Ubuntu jammy installed alongside windows. Windows boots normally but after running the above command and restarting Ubuntu now gets stuck in the screen showing the logo of the PC manufacturer and Ubuntu which normally would be followed by the login screen.
Any ideas how I can fix this? I tried removing the user again through the recovery root console but to no avail.

EDIT: It works when I boot "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-43-generic" from the advanced options but obviously I want the standard Ubuntu config to work again.

The version that is not working anymore is "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-56-generic"

Comment: try removing the kernel using apt and then upgrade the kernel again by `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: @RishonJR so I ran the commands you highlighted but nothing changed. You said to remove the kernel? How do I do that? I'm assuming that's a separate thing to do? Can you elaborate a little bit on that? Linux 5.15.0-43-generic is the kernel right? If I were to remove that, where would I even run sudo apt? Because you have to select a kernel before you can access the recovery root shell.

Comment: Follow the [1st answer of this askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253347/how-to-easily-remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts) and then run the commands that I mentioned above.

Comment: You have to remove the not-so-working kernel(5.15.56)