# No space in root

Tags: 20.04, root, disk, disk-usage, storage

The moment I try to install something, I get an error of insufficient disk storage. In the above screenshot, there is a mismatch of space left in root for reasons I can't figure out. Last time when I ignored the message of insufficient disk storage, I starting facing infinite loop issues. Can you please suggest a permanent fix for this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use `baobab`, it will show you the space use by folder.

Comment: The  root partition is only 19GB, and 94% is used.

Comment: 19Gb is more than enough for a desktop. So please explain why / contains 17Gb? Did you install a mysql  and have a large database in there? Or websites? If you do ... those do not belong on / and need a personal mount point

Comment: Should I keep my desktop clean? Where should I store the Desktop files?

Comment: I'm not able to figure out how to check what is consuming al the space

Comment: @MalikaArora You can find large files consuming much space in root partition. 

find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -h | sort -rh | head -n 10

Comment: @MalikaArora *"I'm not able to figure out how to check what is consuming al the space"* I suggested in my first comment an application that does just that.

Comment: `filelight` is also an app that will help you discover what's taking up the most space.  It will show pie chart representations of the size of files and folders within a given path.  I suggest that you STOP using the OS and switch to a live session. The longer you operate your system with no free space, you increase the chance of the system encountering an unrecoverable catastrophe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space) and [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In a terminal run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall deborphan
sudo deborphan
sudo apt --purge remove $(deborphan)
sudo deborphan --libdevel
sudo apt --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
sudo deborphan --find-config
sudo dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
sudo rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
```

=========================================

For a permanent solution, you should periodically run, after application installations and system updates.

These commands:

```
sudo deborphan
sudo apt --purge remove $(deborphan)
sudo deborphan --libdevel
sudo apt --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
sudo deborphan --find-config
sudo dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
```

Comment: Please check the second image. It got reduced to 90%. Please suggest a permanent fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Inodes (df -i) shows how many inodes (file, dirs, links) you have not their block ( space) usage.

In your case you have very few but big files.

To know where these files are is a good start. To check this you need to run (as root) something like:

```
cd / && du -d 1 -m | sort -n -r
```

Which gives you the size in MB of every single directory.

This is a good start to know if you have too many data (usually in /home) or too many softwares (usually in /usr or /opt) or a lot of garbage (usually in /var)