# cleaning up /dev/sda3

Tags: cleanup

I keep getting message 'Low diskspace on Filesystem root' and it mentions '/dev/sda3'.

So I do 'df -h', which tells:

[image]

How do I clean up sda3 to make more space available?

Comment: First, stop considering the device `/dev/sda3`, and, instead, consider the filesystem, `/`. Investigate filesystem space usage with `sudo du --one-file-system --block-size=1m /`. Read `man logrotate` to see about cleaning `/var/log` safely.

Comment: You may find this helpful: [How do I free up disk space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space)