# What is safe to exclude for a full system backup?

Tags: backup, cache, thumbnails

I'm looking for a list which paths/files are safe to exclude for a full system/home backup.

*Considering that I have a list of installed packages.*

- `/home/*/.thumbnails`
- `/home/*/.cache`
- `/home/*/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/Cache`
- `/home/*/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/OfflineCache`
- `/home/*/.local/share/Trash`
- `/home/*/.gvfs/`
- `/tmp/`
- `/var/tmp/`
- not real folders but can cause severe problems when 'restoring'

  - `/dev`
  - `/proc`
  - `/sys`

What about...

- `/var/` in general?
- `/var/backups/` - can get quite large
- `/var/log/` - does not require much space and can help for later comparison
- `/lost+found/`

Comment: This is an (very) related answer worth looking at (assuming this isn't closed as a duplicate) : http://askubuntu.com/questions/5596/how-to-clean-caches-in-my-homedir/5610#5610

Comment: I am not sure about `/home/*/.local/share/Trash`. I already restored files from trash folder on backup. It was a mistaken deletion, noticed and undone after I made backups - and on restoring backups files were still in trash.

Comment: ~/.local/share/Trash/* seems to be universal, but is by user.

Comment: Note that this was posted in 2011.  Your mileage may vary in 2017.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When I `rsync` my system to a backup partition, I exclude these:

```
--exclude=/dev/* \
--exclude=/home/*/.gvfs \
--exclude=/home/*/.mozilla/firefox/*/Cache \
--exclude=/home/*/.cache/chromium \
--exclude=/home/*/.thumbnails \
--exclude=/media/* \
--exclude=/mnt/* \
--exclude=/proc/* \
--exclude=/sys/* \
--exclude=/tmp/* \
--exclude=/home/*/.local/share/Trash \
--exclude=/etc/fstab \
--exclude=/var/run/* \
--exclude=/var/lock/* \
--exclude=/lib/modules/*/volatile/.mounted \
--exclude=/var/cache/apt/archives/* \
```

This way I am able to boot into the backup partition the same way I can boot to the original one.

So to sum up, I would suggest

- not excluding `/{dev,proc,media,...}` themselves, just their contents
- excluding `/var/{run,lock}`, and especially the big `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

Comment: You want to exclude ALL of /dev.

Comment: @psusi - Yes, you are right. I'm editing my post. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend using the -x option with rsync for backups. That way, it will not cross filesystem boundaries, which will exclude things like /dev /proc /sys /mnt and /media. You still have to exclude /home/*/.gvfs.

Comment: @Azendale: might be. On the other hand, when you use something like `--exclude=/proc/*`, it will keep the directory /proc on the backup (which is needed if you want to boot the mirror), but not the contents of it.

Comment: or Opera users , I would add `--exclude=/home/*/.opera/cache` as well :)

Comment: maybe a naive question, but why `/etc/fstab` has been excluded as well?

Comment: @Guandalino: `/etc/fstab` should be edited manually if you want to be able to boot into the backup partition. Otherwise it's not necessary to exclude that file.

Comment: What flags would you suggest for rsync? Or better what would be the full command to do a backup like this over ssh to a remote machine?

Comment: Firefox [stores it's cache](http://askubuntu.com/q/616551/14601) in `/home/*/.cache/mozilla/*` these days instead of `/home/*/.mozilla/firefox/*/Cache/`

Comment: The huge files are /var/log/kern* and var/log/messages* - are they safe to exclude?

Answer (score 6):

I'll recomend to exclude all `/usr` (except fort `/usr/local/`) and have a backup of `dpkg --get-selections`

In my opinion a Full backup isn't really usefull. I rather prefer backup data and preferences and then restore packages from the official repositories.

But is my preference...

`/usr` contains mainly static binary content from distribution packages. Reinstalling a package will restore `/usr` contents. Also `/bin` and `/sbin` contains binaries from distribution packages.

`/usr/local` contains manually installed packages (out of distribuition packages). so this is worth to backup.

Comment: Very interesting approach. It will yield a significantly smaller backup, but require way more trouble (time, internet bandwidth) when restoring. A compromise that may be worth in some use cases. Questions: how about `/lib`, the same applies? And how do you *restore* such package selection?

Comment: Yes, I think you can also exclude `/lib`. I'd add also that instead of `dpkg --get-selections` it's maybe better to use `apt-mark`, as said here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/101931/restoring-all-data-and-dependencies-from-dpkg-set-selections

Answer (score 2):

I also read all of the answers and all the other related questions when I was configuring my full system backup.

My 2 cents would be not to exclude anything but only when you are doing a full system backup of an offline system.

Let me elaborate now:
If you backing up the system from within itself, then you may exclude some directories as others have mentioned but this is not a good way in my opinion as it can introduce some bugs later on when restoring the system. For example, if you exclude /tmp directory, then after restoring it, /tmp won't be there and system will create one and this can have stuck login screens due to chmod & chown issues on /tmp. Also not backing up ~/.cache directory can result in breaking up database cache of Ubuntu Software Centre.

What I do is use a live CD and use LuckyBackup and backup the entire system without omitting anything. Now when restoring, I chose 'delete files not present in the source'. This way you will have an entire system snapshot restored exactly to the state when you created the backup (kinda like snapshotting a VM).

Comment: Many files are not supposed to be saved because they are **not** real files, but rather *pseudo-files*. You may want want to save caches, but don't save the contents of `/proc`, `/dev`, `sys`. Their contents are created on boot.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior When this approach is followed and the backup is done from an *offline* system, the contents of these not-real files are already empty.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry! I didn't pay attention to the LiveCD you mentioned.

Comment: I'm afraid these systems have to run 24x7 so don't have that luxury.  I have a great exclude list but keep getting hung up on 4G /var/log/kern* and /var/log/messages* - I would like to exclude them but nobody talks to that.  How about excluding /var/log/* totally?