# Using versioning for settings in home?

Tags: settings, version-control

I planned to use `git` for the important files in my home directory, so I can revert bad settings or transfer them to another computer as needed. But there's too much chaos there, with each program mixing wildly temporary files, caches, logs, backups, and everything.

Finding anything worth saving is hard, and when I've found any settings done by myself, there were mixed with informations specific to the computer (so I could hardly take them to another one) and timestamps (so tracking useful changes is hard).

Is anybody doing it or is it just hopeless and how to filter out the garbage?

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28477/what-is-safe-to-exclude-for-a-full-system-backup) has some pretty good tips on things you can definitely ignore from any sort of versioning. Typically runtime or cached things that would be regenerated.