# Having a list of paths, how can I filter out subdirectories of previously mentioned paths?

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing, paths

Let's say I have a sorted list of absolute paths, like the one in my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/864572/367990) (shortened and modified for this question):

```
/proc
/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
/run
/run/cgmanager/fs
/run/hugepages/kvm
/run/lock
/run/user/1000
/run/user/1000/gvfs
/tmp
/home/bytecommander/ramdisk
```

What I want is to reduce this list by eliminating all paths which are subdirectories of previously mentioned paths. That means, for the given input I want this output:

```
/proc
/run
/tmp
/home/bytecommander/ramdisk
```

How can this be done easily in the command-line using e.g. Bash, `sed`, `awk` or any other common tools? Short solutions that fit in one line are appreciated but not required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### AWK

```
$ awk -F '/' 'oldstr && NR>1{ if($0!~oldstr"/"){print $0;oldstr=$0}};NR == 1{print $0;oldstr=$0}'  paths.txt 
/proc
/run
/tmp
/home/bytecommander/ramdisk
/var/zomg
/var/zomgkthx
/zomg
/zomgkthx
```

The way this works is simple enough, but order of commands is significant. We start by recording what the first line is and printing it out. We go to following line and check if the next line contains previous text. If it does - we do nothing. If it doesn't - that's a different, new path.

The original approach was flawed and failed when there were adjacent paths with same leading substring, such as `/var/zomg` and `/var/zomgkthx` (Thanks to Chai T.Rex for pointing that out). The trick is to append "/" to old path to signify ending of it, thus breaking the substring. Same approach is used in python alternative below.

#### Python alternative

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys,os

oldline = None
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
     for index,line in enumerate(f):
         path = line.strip()
         if index == 0 or not line.startswith(oldline):
             print(path)
             oldline = os.path.join(path,'')
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./reduce_paths.py paths.txt                                                                                     
/proc
/run
/tmp
/home/bytecommander/ramdisk
/var/zomg
/var/zomgkthx
/zomg
/zomgkthx
```

This approach is similar to awk-one. Idea is the same: record the first line, and keep printing and resetting the tracking variable only when we encounter line that doesn't have tracking variable as a starting substring.

Alternatively, once could use `os.path.commonprefix()` function as well.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys,os

oldline = None
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
     for index,line in enumerate(f):
         path = line.strip()
         if index == 0 or os.path.commonprefix([path,oldline]) != oldline:
             print(path)
             oldline = os.path.join(path,'')
```

Comment: The `awk` command seems to fail for `/zomg\n/zomgkthx` The second line, `/zomgkthx` isn't a subdirectory of `/zomg`, but it's eliminated.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex  that's one of the pitfalls  I was mentioning in the last paragraph.   I don't see how to to improve it so far, unfortunately.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I've implemented that in my python version. Please see updated answer.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex improved it even more. Now it should work for variable length paths

Answer (score 8):

Another Python version, using the new `pathlib` library:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import pathlib, sys

seen = set()
for l in sys.stdin:
    p = pathlib.Path(l.strip())
    if not any(x in seen for x in p.parents):
        seen.add(p)
        print(str(p))
```